# Ubuntu 20.04 desktop too many polkit prompts - Authentication required

Tags: ubuntu, policykit

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop. After the upgrade, am receiving way too many pol kit prompts. Its just outrageous. One for sleep, one for poweroff, selecting wifi network, scanning wifi network (every 10 secs), mounting disks to name a few.

I understand these are for security reasons, but would be nice if it has an option to remember authentication. Some of these prompts are odd in that they are fairly common desktop tasks. Can I execute a script that adds exception for some them?

Comment: Does one of [these solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98006/how-do-i-prevent-policykit-from-asking-for-a-password) work for you?

Comment: Not exactly, since the solution is more of a hack where its all disabled or we have to add exceptions by hand. Am looking at a script or a gui tool that monitors a prompt and allows adding exception permanently when the prompt appears first time.